# Remove _id from returned records from MongoDB

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb

I want to remove the "_id" from all documents returned by MongoDB; this code does not work:

```
const res = await findPromise<Omit<TaleGroupDB, "_id">>(
        "table1",
        { provider },
        undefined,
        proxy
    );
```

Why does "Omit" not work?
The query returns record like

```
{_id: ObjectId, field1: "text1", field2: "test2"}
```

Expected result:

```
{field1: "text1", field2: "test2"}
```

Comment: Typescript is just a Typed layer on top of JavaScript. It does not execute anything. So, your `Omit` tells the reader that the result won't have `_id`, but that's it. Have look into Lodash library, they provide tools such as `_.omit` which removes items from object.

Comment: Why don't you use [projection stage](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#projection) like [this example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-XRWwUNPqDO)

Comment: @J.F. : unfortunately, I cannot modify the findPromise function; I should loop on the res array to remove the _id